# ERROR: for azerothcore-wotlk_ac-database_1 Cannot start service ac-database: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

With Docker on Windows, when using `docker-compose up` , I get error message from console (git bash)

**Command used:** `docker-compose up`

Docker compose file: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

**Results:**

> ERROR: for azerothcore-wotlk_ac-database_1  Cannot start service ac-database: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint azerothcore-wotlk_ac-database_1 (a999876eaab9126abc6635a5d62ab31c5e14fd12439ec2747a42e72fb923a4af): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3306:tcp:172.19.0.2:3306: input/output error
>
> ERROR: for ac-database  Cannot start service ac-database: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint azerothcore-wotlk_ac-database_1 (a999876eaab9126abc6635a5d62ab31c5e14fd12439ec2747a42e72fb923a4af): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3306:tcp:172.19.0.2:3306: input/output error ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: Update your question with docker-compose file?

Comment: @vitoco-godoy have you tried restarting docker?

Answer (score 2):

I did followed this link, 
http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker

and at first got the same message of yours.

The Problem is that the docker version have mysql in it, 
and if you have installed mysql in the machine, you must uninstall it first.

(maybe, net stop mysql)

After that, docker-compose up runs well.